# Python Selenium warning "DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, deprecation-warning

I have multiple elements with the same class_name (table-number). I am trying to find specific ones based on their sequence. In this case [1], the first one that appears in the DOM.

Here is working code:

```
my_table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use
> find_element() instead

I know I can ignore it, but it's annoying. I tried different syntax, such as:

```
my_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text

my_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text
```

What should be correct syntax? Am I approaching it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Upgrading** your Python version will not help solve this issue, since `find_element` is a Selenium-specific function.

`driver.find_element_by_*` has been deprecated in **Selenium 4 newer version**.

So you should be using

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text
```

The first one that you are using:

```
my_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text
```

has an extra `(`.

And the second one

```
my_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text
```

seems correct.

Comment: my_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of

```py
my_table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text
```

With new style will be

```py
my_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='table-number'])[1]").text
```

The general syntaxes are:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_locator_string)
```

and

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_locator_string)
```